# Firefox mozilla web extensions : How to know when a tab has finished loading, from the background page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, mozilla, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to perform action after Page loaded through web extension in mozilla ,

I have tried same method available in chrome as bellow

```
 browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId , info) {
   if (info.status === 'complete') {
   // your code ...
   }
});
```

But it is not working well I am not getting "complete" status in some of cases,sometimes multiple iframes are there in web page.

So is there any solution to check weather page loading completed?

Comment: I guess webNavigation.onCompleted and frameId == 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use following code to solve your problem:

```
browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (tab.status == "complete" && tab.active) { 
      // Perform you task after page loaded completely 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried a way that @wOxxOm suggested to me in comment and it is also working fine:

```
browser.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(details) {
    if (details.frameId == 0) {
        // Here you can perform tasks after page load completed
    }
});
```